# Pictures music and videos not showing

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage

I am having this issue from last 1 month. Whatever pictures I am receiving or videos or music I am downloading is not visible to me in the gallery or the video or music app. But it is visible in the file explorer. My phone does not support SD card. It already posses 16 gb memory.

I don't know what I have done. May be I have deleted some important cache files or something like that. Only the pictures I am capturing is visible in the gallery. I scanned my music app as well but it does not show me the new songs I have added. Same problem with the video app.. Every time I have to visit the file explorer to see these things.
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your photos/videos/music are not inside android folder of your phone. Those places are usually skipped by the scanner. Power cycle your phone if possible. If nothing works you might wanna reset your phone from settings-> backup and reset

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use your file explorer and go to its settings and enable `Show hidden files`.

Now navigate to the folder where you received the images/music and look for a file named `.nomedia`. This file tells the OS to not look for media in that folder. You can delete that file and your media should now show up in the Gallery.

It might take a couple of minutes for your phone to reindex once the `.nomedia` file is deleted.